# SQL Case - with SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, case

I'm having trouble using a select statement to set a return value in a CASE statement ... can someone please have a look?

```
DECLARE @SystemTypeId int
SELECT @SystemTypeId = [SystemTypeId] FROM [Properties] WHERE [Id] = @PropertyId

SET @RETURN_VAL =
    CASE @SystemTypeId
      WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT [Created] FROM [Assets] WHERE [Id] = @AssetId) 
      WHEN 3 THEN (SELECT dbo.GetAssetValueById([CreatedBy])
                   FROM [Assets]
                   WHERE [Id] = @AssetId)
      WHEN 9 THEN (SELECT [LastModified]
                   FROM [Assets]
                   WHERE [Id] = @AssetId)
      ELSE NULL
    END
```

Comment: Step one would be **declaring `@AssetID`**

Comment: @AssetId is already declare farther up above.

Comment: It seems as if no matter what @SystemTypeId is, case 2 is always chosen.

Comment: Hmm.. you sure? Did you actually test the value of @SystemTypeID by doing 'Print @SystemTypeID'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT @RETURN_VAL =
        CASE @SystemTypeId
            WHEN 2 THEN  [Created] 
            WHEN 3 THEN  dbo.GetAssetValueById([CreatedBy]) 
            WHEN 9 THEN [LastModified] 
            ELSE NULL
        END 
FROM [Assets] 
WHERE [Id] = @AssetId
```

Comment: @a1ex07, you should have only half answered then edited.  Don't know you how to SO?

Comment: It seems as if no matter what @SystemTypeId is, case 2 (the first case) is always chosen.

Comment: I even changed it to this to test:

Comment: I'm a complete moron.  I had already tried this.  Code error in my DAL.

Comment: Randall: try `SELECT @SystemTypeId = 9;`  You'll see that your `@RETURN_VAL` is value of LastModified.